# Is there any software to find differences when upgrading XML schema's?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, upgrade

I'm dealing with a major XML schema upgrade which includes multiple xsd files. I'm using xmlbeans and Java reflection to look for differences and convert test data. Before I write something, is there any software already available?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since XML Schema files are in XML format, you could try some [XML diff utilities](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=xml%20diff) to highlight differences. These won't be smart about Schemas per se, but they would be better than nothing.

There are also some diff tools specific to XML Schema:

- [Altova Diff Dog](http://www.altova.com/diffdog/xml-schema-diff-tool.html) "After you map two XML Schemas, DiffDog® 2011 lets you generate an XSLT file to transform existing XML documents for the new schema by clicking either Copy button on the DiffDog toolbar." I have not tried this tool.
- [XML Zebra](https://launchpad.net/xmlzebra) "an XML Schema differencing tool that works by creating a "fingerprint" file for a set of Schemas. The "fingerprint" contains paths (like XPaths, but extended with extra information) that define what is allowed in valid XML documents for those Schemas. By comparing versions of the "fingerprint" files, both direct and indirect changes to the allowed XML can be detected between versions of the Schemas". I have not tried this either.